# run Watin in silent mode, using Team City

Tags: teamcity, watin, silent

I what to run may watin tester in silent mode and how I can get Team City to run my tests ?

Answer (score 8):

Watin tests can be made to run with IE hidden from view by setting the MakeNewIeInstanceVisible flag. It is true by default.

In the WatiN 2 release candidate, IE can be hidden with:

```
WatiN.Core.Settings.MakeNewIeInstanceVisible = false;
```

I have not tested on earlier WatiN versions but the [releasenotes](http://watin.sourceforge.net/releasenotes-1-2-0-4000.html) for version 1.2.0.4 explains the feature for that version:

> By default WatiN tests make the created Internet Explorer instances visible to the user. You >can run your test invisible by changing the following setting. Be aware that HTMLDialogs and >any popup windows will be shown even if you set this setting to false (this is default >behavior of Internet Explorer which currently can't be suppressed).
>
> > `IE.Settings.MakeNewIeInstanceVisible = false; // default is true`